# Set two different python versions with pyenv with different names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

Is it possible to set two different python versions for different names using `pyenv`? E.g. I want the `python3` refer to version 3.7.4 but `python` refer to version 2 of python defined by system which is 2.7.12 so there will not be any conflicts and issues.

Currently I just can set version globally using `pyenv global 3.7.4` which cause both `python` and `python3` be version 3.7.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pyenv allows you to use different versions of Python at once using "advanced" mode

Example from documentation:

```
$ pyenv local 2.7.6 3.3.3
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.6 (set by /Users/yyuu/path/to/project/.python-version)
* 3.3.3 (set by /Users/yyuu/path/to/project/.python-version)
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3.3 --version
Python 3.3.3
```

For more information, please look at:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local-advanced

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is from a while ago, but I stumbled upon the same problem, and here's the approach that I took.

### To make sure we're on the same page...

Initially, I had (and I assume you do too) both `python` and `python3` pointing to system's Python:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/nigorojr/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.4
$ python --version && pyenv which python
Python 2.7.12
/usr/bin/python
$ python3 --version && pyenv which python3
Python 3.5.2
/usr/bin/python3
```

However, this is what I wanted:

```
$ python --version && pyenv which python
Python 2.7.12
/usr/bin/python
$ python3 --version && pyenv which python3
Python 3.7.4
/home/nigorojr/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python3
```

### Approach

The approach I took is similar to @Kapitol's second suggestion. However, I created a shell script instead of an alias because I wanted other commands (including `pyenv`) to be able to find my new `python3` command.

I created `~/bin/python3` (with `~/bin` in my `$PATH` variable) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PYENV_VERSION="$( pyenv versions | tr -d ' ' | awk '/^3\./ { print $1 }' | tail -n 1 )" pyenv exec python3 $@
# Or simply,
PYENV_VERSION="3.7.4" pyenv exec python3 $@
```

With this shell script, I get:

```
$ python --version && pyenv which python
Python 2.7.12
/usr/bin/python
$ python3 --version && pyenv which python3
Python 3.7.4
/home/nigorojr/bin/python3
```

Note 1: Using `exec python3 $@` instead of `pyenv exec python3 $@` in the shell script does not work because it becomes an infinite recursive call to the script itself (depending on `$PATH`). Using `pyenv exec` ensures that the `pyenv` Python gets called no matter how the `$PATH` variable is ordered.

Note 2: Having all the pipes to get the latest version managed by `pyenv` does slow down the startup when calling `python3`. Thus, I would recommend simply setting your desired Python version in `PYENV_VERSION` if you have a particular version you want to use.

Note 3: Be aware that `pip3` and other commands will not be found with this approach. One solution is to create a shell script for each command that you use. Another solution is to run `pyenv global system 3.7.4` so that `pyenv` can search in 3.7.4 if the command is not installed in the system.

### Checking that it works

To make sure that everything is working as expected, I wrote the following Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and ran:

```
$ ./sample.py
2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
$ python ./sample.py
2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
$ python3 ./sample.py
3.7.4 (default, Sep 16 2019, 16:09:11)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Changing the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, I got:

```
$ ./sample.py
3.7.4 (default, Sep 16 2019, 16:09:11)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
$ python ./sample.py
2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
$ python3 ./sample.py
3.7.4 (default, Sep 16 2019, 16:09:11)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

To conclude, with the abovementioned approach, you can have `python` point to system's Python 2 while having `python3` point to the version installed with `pyenv`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to be explicit when you run your python. ie. Specify the version you want via the PYENV_VERSION environment version. If you have python 2.7.12 installed via pyenv, you should be able to verify with:

```
PYENV_VERSION=2.7.12 python -V
```

You really should be creating a new virtualenv to make sure you don't run into any dependency issues if you decide to run multiple projects with the same python version. Pyenv has a [plugin](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) that supports this. Then you could do something like:

```
pyenv virtualenv 2.7.12 python2-env
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.4 python3-env
```

You can then active your shell with:

```
pyenv shell python3-env
```

In which case `python` would point to the 3.7.4 shim.

Or:

```
pyenv shell python2-env
```

In which case `python` would point to the 2.7.12 shim. (You can call these virtualenvs whatever you like, I just used python2-env and python3-env as an example.)

If you're really set on using python3 and python, you could always set an alias in your .bashrc:

```
alias python3='PYENV_VERSION=3.7.4 python'
alias python='PYENV_VERSION=2.7.12 python'
```

Comment: First half of your answer does not relate to my question and the last technique which could be something I wanted isn't working.

Comment: @MaskedMan Make sure your [pyenv is initialized](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) using `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`, and the versions set to `PYENV_VERSION` are install on your machine by `pyenv install`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Telling people they don't have the problems they articulate is not useful.